# Keeping document scrolled to bottom when document height changes/animates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The footer (or a part of it) on a page I'm working on is collapsible. I also animate the collapse and expansion of this element. The footer isn't fixed (nor do I want it to be) but I would prefer the view to stick to the bottom of the page when the footer is expanding. I've tried handling this in a handful of ways but in all cases, the behavior is the same. When collapsing the footer, the document height gets smaller during the animation and the footer remains anchored to the bottom of the screen. When expanding the footer, the position of the viewport doesn't change, the document height increases and the animation of the footer happens below the fold.

I've handled this animation both using javascript and CSS3. The behavior is the same. I've also tried positioning the footer absolutely and adjusting animating the height of the content above the footer concurrently ... same behavior.

Finally, I've tried some javascript hacks to animate window.scrollTo while other animation is taking place. That this doesn't work is confusing. Here's a basic example of that hack.

```
collapse: function(container,collapsed) {
    var maxHeight = 250,
        steps = 50,
        params = this.animParams(maxHeight,steps,collapsed);

    for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        this.animateCollapse(container,params,i);
    }
},

animateCollapse: function(container,params,i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        container.css('height',params[i]);
        window.scrollTo(0,100000);
    },10);
},

animParams: function(maxHeight, steps, collapsed) {
    var arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        var multiplier = (steps - i) / steps;

        arr.push(maxHeight * multiplier);
    }

    if (!collapsed) {
        arr = arr.reverse();
    }

    return arr;
},
```

In the above example, I'm using a value (100000) that is taller that the document because during that loop, the value returned by $(document).height() doesn't change even though the animation is happening concurrently.

So, in the end, my goal is pretty straightforward -- keep the viewport at the bottom of the screen when the footer height is animating and increasing the height of the document. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the scroll position to the maximum every time you increment the height of the footer in your animation? More code showing how you achieve the animation would be helpful.

Comment: Your example code doesn't make sense. i is undefined, and window.scrollTo will run 100 times within 1 second.

Comment: @jkgeyti - sorry - I dropped that example in too quickly. The example is fixed.

Comment: @mickylaaaad -- I'd prefer to use a CSS3 height animation here. I've also used  jQuery.animate() to the same effect. To your question, let me try animating height of the footer manually ... I'll report back on how that behaves.

Comment: @mickylaaaad - I've updated my original post to show a more detailed example of a manual animation. window.scrollTo(0,100000) is being triggered at every step of the animation, but not affecting the scroll. If I call document.height (in supporting browsers) or $(document).height() at that point, the height of the document prior to entering the loop is always returned.